# Audio playback information when pressing buttons (school project)

Tags: audio, speakers, button

My son is making a display (about A1 sized card) about space for school and I am trying to find out a simple way to add some buttons, that when pressed plays an audio recording with info about different topics. So multiple buttons spread over the display and each buttons plays a specific recording.

My first thought was those little devices in greetings cards that play sounds when opened. But they may be a bit too quiet? They can't be too big as it has to be attached the the card display.

Is there anything that is small, capable of playing back different messages based on which button is pressed?

Answer (score -1):

There are [button recorders for ~US$4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HT5HBMO), though I do not know if that would add any educational value to the project. Similar devices were also used in [training a dog to communicate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJCxrc7Ns_g).